# Watir & Nokogiri not loading content in frame

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Using watir & nokogiri to parse the content I can find in my bank account. The line `browser.div(:id => 'main_layout_v2_1_cell_1:0').wait_until_present` tells watir to wait until the div that is loaded by js appears. (I disabled javascript in Chrome to check if the content is loaded by javascript, and indeed it is.)

Nonetheless when Nokogiri puts `browser.html` it shows all the content except the section loaded by js.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require "watir-webdriver/wait"
require 'nokogiri'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'https://particulares.gruposantander.es/SUPFPA_ENS/BtoChannelDriver.ssobto?dse_operationName=NavLoginSupernet&dse_parentContextName=&dse_processorState=initial&dse_nextEventName=start'

#Login
browser.select_list(:name => 'tipoDocumento').select 'NIF'
browser.text_field(:name => 'numeroDocumento').set 'xxx'
browser.text_field(:name => 'password').set 'xxx'
browser.button(:value => 'Entrar').click

#Select account
browser.link(:title => 'Cuentas').when_present.click
browser.div(:id => 'main_layout_v2_1_cell_1:0').wait_until_present

#Parse what you see, Noko
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
puts page
```

Things I've tried:

1. If I'm parsing the whole HTML through Nokogiri is because first I have tried to get those links I want to click finding by ID, title, text. None of them worked because as Nokogiri shows in the output, that part of code is not present.
2. Extending the timeout and rescueing the error to give the browser more time to make sure the code is there.

Code here:
    begin

```
Timeout::timeout(40) do
    #Parse what you see, Noko
    page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
    puts page
  end
    puts 'done'
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  puts 'not done :/'
end
```

3. Wait_until a div present in the content loaded by js is present > `browser.wait_until{browser.div(:id => 'main_layout_v2_1_cell_1:0').exist?}` > Timeout error.

Notes: the content I'm trying to get is wrapped in a body tag with this structure `<body scroll="auto" bgcolor="F4F6F7" onload="main.onload();">`

The code parsed by Nokogiri only outputs the content that is not loaded by js. How to load that content too?

Comment: Given that you said the content is wrapped in a body tag, it makes me think that the page is using iframes. The `browser.html` will not include the HTML in frames. Instead, you would need to parse the iframe itself - eg `page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.iframe.html)`. If that is not it, it might help to give an actual example of the HTML.

Comment: Right @JustinKo , that outputs the part of code that I was looking for - still not parsed out, but it outputs what I was looking for. Set that as answer and I will mark it as valid, thanks! I supposed that if there was no <iframe> in the visible source code why I was going to try with that option though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `html` method only does not include the contents of frames and iframes. As a result, if the desired content is within a frame, you need to explicitly tell Watir to return the frame HTML.

Assuming there is only 1 iframe on the page, you would do:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.iframe.html)
```